# Requisição para API de tempo em tempo

Tags: c#, api

Estou precisando realizar requisições para uma API de tempo em tempo por exemplo, a cada 10 segundos, não tenho conhecimento de nenhuma forma para fazer isso, seria semelhante ao `SetInterval` do javascript porém no C#, as outras informações já tenho link da API método e informações só desconheço uma função para fazer isso ou forma de requisitar de tempo em tempo, Obrigado!

Comment: Essa Api é sua? Ou é de um terceiro?

Comment: é uma API de Terceiros.

Comment: e no C#, está usando o que ? Winforms, asp.net, console, ... ?